# Leaflet How To Update User Position Marker Real Time

Tags: leaflet, geolocation, real-time

I am trying to update user position in leaflet. Like when the user walks with their phone their location marker will move too based on location data just like Google Maps.

Right now I'm just putting a marker on their initial position

```
    this.map.locate({
  setView: true,
  maxZoom: 120
}).on("locationfound", e => {

  leaflet.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude]).bindPopup("YOU ARE HERE!").addTo(this.map);



  console.log("lokasyon bulundu");
}).on("locationerror", error => {

  console.log("lokasyon bulunamadi");
});
```

Tried update() method but couldn't make it work. I guess I should take user location data every second and if it is different then draw a new marker and remove the old one?

Is this an efficient way?

edit: tried this but not working

```
this.map.locate({
        setView: true,
        maxZoom: 120,
        watch:true,
        enableHighAccuracy:true
      }).on("locationfound", e => {
          if (!usermarker) {

            if(this.profileData.avatar == "https://i.hizliresim.com/zJJ239.png"){
              usermarker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{icon : ayi}).addTo(this.map);
            }else if(this.profileData.avatar == "https://i.hizliresim.com/mJJrkP.png"){
              usermarker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{icon : ironman}).addTo(this.map);
            }else if(this.profileData.avatar == "https://i.hizliresim.com/vJJQpp.png"){
              usermarker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{icon : dino}).addTo(this.map);
            }else if(this.profileData.avatar == "https://i.hizliresim.com/zJJ2B9.png"){
              usermarker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{icon : petyr}).addTo(this.map);
            }
          } else if(this.profileData.avatar == "https://i.hizliresim.com/zJJ239.png") {
              usermarker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
          }
      }).on("locationerror", error => {
          if (usermarker) {
              map.removeLayer(usermarker);
              usermarker = undefined;
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 6):

For continous watch add option

```
watch: true
```

Here http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#locate-options is the list of all locate options.

This is the code I tested (Android 7.0) and that works for me:

```
function onLocationFound(e) {
  var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
  L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();
  L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
map.locate({setView: true, watch: true, maxZoom: 8});
```

Comment: Hi i tried something added on first post put its not working.

Comment: Modified my answer with the code that works for me.